# Change footer style on some pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have a WordPress web site. I want to show some elements in footer just on my home page. But those show up on every pages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by simple condition :

```
   <?php if (is_home()) { ?>
        //Call footer for home
    <?php } ?>
```